# is there a defaultValue property for radio select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am wondering if there is a way to reset a radio to it's originally selected option. I know of `defaultValue` for inputs but is there a way to make it so that I can reset the radios back to their originally selected value on page load?

I am not wanting to simply unselect all radios. I am trying to put them back to their originally selected value.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: If you want to reset the form, use the `reset` method of the `HTMLFormElement` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, radio inputs do have `defaultValue` property, but what you are looking for is the `defaultChecked` property:

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function() {
   return this.defaultChecked;
});
```

That being said, if you want to reset the form you can use the `reset` method of the `HTMLFormElement` object:

```
$('#formElement').get(0).reset();
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't realize it'd be that simple. Thanks! I'm not really resetting a form, I just want to mimic the behavior for a form field outside of a form. This worked perfectly.

Comment: @Jeremy You are very welcome. There are many methods and properties  swept under the carpet that can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="true"/>Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
    <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>
```

Any time you will reset the form, the `male` radio button will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I will rather make a jQuery plugin like this:

```
$.fn.defaultVal = function (checked) {
    if(checked === true || checked === false) {
        $(this).attr("data-default", checked);
        return;
    }
    if(!$(this).attr("data-default")) {
        console.log("No default value assigned!");
        return;
    }
    return $(this).attr("data-default");
}
```

**JSFIDDLE LINK UPDATE**
Working Demo is here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/69aaX/4/)

Comment: `$(this).prop("checked", $(this).prop("defaultChecked"));` this handles the default checked value the way I need, no point in re-inventing the wheel but still a good work-a-round if needed.